# slash or no slash in front of assets path (html)

Tags: html, path, relative-path

is it a good practice to use `/` in front of paths in html pages?
If using `/` for paths, should I set a `<base url="">` in my page?

I'm having an issue with a generated css spitting out the following:

```
background-image: url("/images/pizza.jpg");
```

as the website is in a domain subfolder, let's say `domain.com/project` I have a 404 error in the console because the resource is pointing to `domain.com/images/pizza.jpg` instead of `domain.com/project/images/pizza.jpg`

I don't want to set `<base url="domain.com/project">` ..

In this specific case, how do I work this out?

In general: is it a good practice using `/` in front of paths, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Use `./` which will point to the current directory (/project).

I use it for a link to the homepage in a subdir (index.php).

And in css it's common to use `../images/pizza.jpg`, which means go one folder up and then select the images folder.

Comment: its not ../ because it's in <style>. I've put ./ as base, but with that slash in the path it's still looking for the resource in the wrong place